# How do I Increase FinalizerThread's priority to collect objects in GC

Tags: java, linux, jvm, linux-kernel

I have monitor my java application with profiler to know memory leak. And I got class which taking almost 80% of memory which is

```
java.lang.ref.Finalizer
```

Then I google it for above class and found great article 
http://www.fasterj.com/articles/finalizer1.shtml

Now can any one suggest me how do I increase FinalizerThread's priority to collect those object's in GC.

One more thing I am facing this issue on Linux with kernel version **Linux 2.6.9-5.ELsmp (i386)** and **Linux 2.6.18-194.17.4.el5 (i386)** but it's working fine (without OOM Error) on **Linux 2.6.18-128.el5PAE (i386).**

Is this issue because of Linux Kernels?
Is there any JVM variable to improve FinalizerThread's priority?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Good question , I think you need in general minimize the use of Finalizers .

Comment: Perhaps in PAE mode you simply have more memory available (non-PAE is limited to 4GB) - check `free`. I don't think the kernel version is at play here.

Comment: Thanks Dan, As Peter suggest below, I am now checking with file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question literally you can do this.  However as outlined below, it is likely to be pointless, esp as the Thread already has a high priority.

```
for(Thread t: Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet())
    if (t.getName().equals("Finalizer")) {
        System.out.println(t);
        t.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        System.out.println(t);
    }
```

prints

```
Thread[Finalizer,8,system]
Thread[Finalizer,10,system]
```

---

Unless you are using 100% of all your cores, or close to it, the priority doesn't matter because even the lowest priority will get as much CPU as it want.

Note: On Linux, it will ignore raised priorities unless you are root.

Instead you should reduce the work the finalizer is doing.  Ideally it shouldn't have anything to do.  One cause of high load in the finalizer is creating resources which should be closed but are being discarded. (leaving the finalizer to close the resource instead)

In short, you should try and determine what resources are being finalized and make sure they don't need to do anything when finalize() is called, ideally don't use this method at all.

It is possible that resources are taking slight longer to close on the older version of the Linux kernel. I would check that the hardware is identical as this could mean it takes longer to clean up resource. (But the real fix is to ensure it doesn't need to do this)

Comment: Is java can make difference. Because First two Linux(where OOM issue arise), am using 64 bit java and one where it's working fine, am using 32 bit?

Comment: The Java version, whether you are using 64bit or 32bit, what hardware you are using CPU, memory, disk, network bandwidth, the workload, e.g. is it doing different work, how busy the resources being closed are e.g. if they connect to a database or service all make a difference in this case. The kernel version might make a difference but I would check the first list first.

Comment: If you have an older version of Java, the 64-bit version can use more memory than the 32-bit version. If you have the latest version the difference is much smaller (as it uses `-XX:+UseCompressedOops`) The real fix is to fix the code, not tinker with the JVM.

Comment: Peter, thanks for your valuable inputs, But I can't fix from code because we are using one third party jar to create one xml script which is going to use for our flash UI. That's the reason I am trying to find out difference between two systems, Because it's working on one system and hang with other.

Comment: If you can determine what the resource which is not being cleaned up quickly that can give you a hint. Is it a database connection, file handle, socket etc.

Comment: it's file handle. That jar is trying to create new XML file and might be closing it in finalize() method.

Comment: So the speed of your files system will be critical.  Do you have write cache enabled? Do you have a HDD, raid controller or SSD?  A problem with not closing files properly is that it can leave the file truncated. It can also mean you run out of file handles when you don't need to.

Comment: We are using raid controller. Which one is better to handle files using java on Linux?

Comment: SSD (of at least 240 GB) is likely to be the fastest (Typically they can sustain 400+ MB/s and 80K+ IOPS), a RAID controller with a write cache enabled next, a hard drive with the write cache enable (less reliable but faster than not having a write cache) A HDD with no write cache is be just 80 IOPS (not 80K)

Comment: Even on JVMs where the priority makes a difference, it might not work if set after the thread has started. (Checking for the name is also a bit JRE specific.)

Comment: And thread priority only affects CPU scheduling, it has no effect on IO, or network bandwidth, or cache/memory usage. ;)

Comment: Hi Peter, I have resolved issue. We upgrade our Velocity jar from 1.4 to 1.7. In 1.4 they have used one class which contains finalyze() method Now that class is deprecated in latest version of Velocity. Because of this change our OOM issue also got resolved. But again one Q is there, that why it's giving error on one system and working fine on other one. Once again, Thanks for you help.

Comment: I assume on one system it can keep up with the file.close() (which flushes data to disk) and on the other system it can't keep up. When it can't keep up, the queue can grow until resources are exhausted.  A slower disk sub-system or a faster CPU (as it could be creating these faster) could be the critical difference.

Comment: If I am understanding in right way Is file.close() works differently on different systems. If yes, how can I come to know which one is there on my system? Is there any way to change it? Or is it related with OS i.e. Linux kernel?

Comment: file.close() works the same on all systems.  How often you might call it (if it is the end of some processing) and long it takes depends on your hardware.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Don't you think it makes more sense to let the *Finalizer* thread close resources instead of normal / *main* thread?. Because `Finalizer` thread has higher priority. Since the `finalize()` method of (say) `FileInputStream` calls `close()` after checking for FD.

Answer (score 2):

The finaliser thread should rarely be doing much work. The resources should already have been released. Make sure your code is handling resources in the standard way.

Java SE 7:

```
try (final Resource resource = acquire()) {
    use(resource);
}
```

Pre-Java SE 7:

```
final Resource resource = acquire();
try {
    use(resource);
} finally {
    resource.release();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Tom Hawtin points out, you can get hold of the FinalizerThread by creating a `finalize()` method that calls `Thread.currentThread()` and then stashes it in a static.  You can probably change its priority too.

But there's a good chance it won't do any good.  There is likely to only be one finalizer thread.  And the problem is likely to be either that:

- the thread can't keep up because there's simply too much work to be done, or
- the thread is being blocked by something you are doing in the finalizer methods.

(And, I'd expect the finalizer thread to *already* be marked as high priority.)

But either way, I think that a better solution is to get rid of the `finalize()` methods.  I bet that they are doing something that is either unnecessary ... or dodgy.  In particular, using finalizers to reclaim resources from dropped objects is a poor way to solve that particular problem.  (See Tom Hawtin's answer.)

Comment: Get hold of finaliser thread object? Easy. Create an object with a finaliser that stashed `Thread.currentThread()` in a static.